# Работоспособность в Excel-2003 макросов, созданных в более поздних версиях

Tags: excel, vba

Мне нужно использовать excel с расширением xls, но макросы некоторые не работают, которые работают на xlsm.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) Dim objCell As Range
    If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:I"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        For Each objCell In Target
            With objCell
                If Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                    Select Case .Column
                    Case 1, 2
                        If TypeName(.Value) = "String" Then
                            .Value = Left(.Value, 10)
                        Else
                            .Value = ""
                        End If
                    Case 4, 5
                       If .Value <> 0 And .Value <> 1 Then .Value = ""
                    Case 6, 7
                       .Value = Replace(.Value, ";", "")
                    Case 8, 9
                       If Not IsNumeric(.Value) Then .ClearContents
                    End Select
                End If
            End With
        Next objCell

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Макрос такой в xls ничего не выполняет. В xlsm работает.

**Вопрос:** каким образом можно использовать макросы в xls?

Comment: опишите вопрос подробней, приведите пример макроса, если хотите получить корректный ответ.

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать xlsm?

Comment: Потому, что данные заносятся в базу с помощью импорта файлов, где есть поддержка xls и xlsx форматов, но нет xlsm. Я хочу наложить на файлы макросы для проверки данных - затем записать в базу.

Comment: http://forum.msexcel.ru/index.php/topic,11513.0.html По ссылке проверили, код в Excel-2003 работает.

Comment: данные очистил - после этого заработало. Спасибо Вам. vikttur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Показанный автором код в *Excel-2003* работает.

Возможные причины неработоспособности в *Exel-2003* макросов, созданных в более поздних версиях.

Использование методов, которые появились позже, вызовет ошибку при применении в *Excel-2003*. Например, втречались случаи неработающей сортировки.

Ошибка может быть, если код записан макрорекодером и запись после него не оптимизирована. Например: форматирование ячейки можно записать одной строкой; макрорекодер выдаст около 10 параметров, среди которых есть несовместимые со старой версией.

В *Excel-2003* 2^16 строк, в *Excel-2010* - 2^20. Если в коде встречается ссылка на ячейку или диапазон ниже строки 65536 - ошибка.

В *Excel-2010* можно использовать функций API для 64-битной версии, *Excel-2003* этого не умеет.

Возможно, проблемный код использует библиотеки, которых нет/не подключены.

'  ---------------

Как-то автоматически установить дружбу макросов новых версий и *Excel-2003* не получится. Нужно просматривать код и удалять изъяны.

Comment: Я так понял xls расширение использовалось в 2003 excel? Никаких ограничений, что описано в ответе там не используется. Т. о. всё должно работать корректно и в 2003.

Comment: Ура всё заработало. Странно очистил все данные после этого. Всем спасибо. Главная благодарность vikttur